# Copy/Move Visual Studio Projects/Solutions To Another Computer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

So I have a handful of Visual Studio projects that I need to move to another computer. Is it as simple as a copy and paste or will that mess something up? Both machines will have the same version of Visual Studio installed, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Is there an export function that I've overlooked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the Visual Studio version is the same, you can just copy the project folder.

Comment: If you are using any external dll's or Ocx's you will need to insure they are installed and their paths are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Till the time you are moving your solution file and associated files you should be good.

In case you are using any source control update your solution from there.

Hope you have the same VS version and any addon frameworks you have

Answer (score 2):

You can directly copy the project to the projects folder. This worked perfectly for Visual C++ projects for me (and also some other projects). But when I copied my Cordova App from one PC to the other (Both had Visual Studio 2015), I wasn't able to open the project. Whenever I tried to open the project, trying both the ways - directly from the Project file and the open option in Visual Studio, it at first opened but when I tried to open a file, it just got hung and didn't respond.

This problem may occur because Cordova apps have some configuration files that might be different for different PCs. I am not sure that this is the reason for the problem.

A solution that I used was that I created a new Project and copied the files to the project folders (excluding the configuration files).

Answer (score 0):

Can you save the file to cloud? if so then you could potentially upload the file to cloud and download the file to the new